# Newton's Method plot

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, homework

[image]

I'm trying to do c. So far I tried,

```
FindRootPlot[
    kθ - FLsinθ], {θ, 0.9}, Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> None}
    F = 1
    k = 8
    L = 10
    θ = 0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Need spaces between values in a product such as m l and not ml.  Also good programming practice to use lower case letters to begin variable names since upper case used by internal functions.  Then just define a function and feed it to FindRoot.  Note the t_ which represents any value supplied to f and not just f[t].
I used myF and myL.  I could have either specified the constants in the function definition or use replacement rules such as k->8 and such below:

```
f[t_] := k t - myF myL Sin[t];
FindRoot[f[t] == 0 /. {k -> 8, myL -> 10, myF -> 1}, {t, 0.9}]

Out[4]= {t -> 1.1311}
```

Comment: it seems like it doesn't work. FIndRoot: The function value (-7.83327+kt} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {t}={0.9}

Comment: Try copying and pasting my code into a notebook.  Looks like in your comment above you entered kt without the space between k and t.  Need the space for a product.

Comment: FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-7.83327 + kt} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {t} = {0.9}.

Comment: I copied and pasted it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is possibly a version issue.  I'm using ver. 12.0.0.  What ver. are you using?

Comment: 12.0.0.0 student edition

Comment: Ok, how about hard-code it:  FindRoot[8 t-10 Sin[t]==0,{t,0.9}].  Surely that will work with any version.  Remember to add space between 8 and t and 10 and Sin[t].

Comment: it works!. Thank you!

Comment: can I ask another question?

Comment: @KassidyMoy I bet `f` is polluted. Check `DownValues[f]`, and you should find something.  `Clear[f]` first before executing Dominic's code should resolve the issue.

Comment: @corey979 and Karsten 7. Please notice OP was asking another question by editing Dominic's answer.

Comment: @KassidyMoy Please start a new question for a new problem. Please don't insert a question into other's answer.

Comment: It was a question about the problem above, for Dominic. It's not a new problem. @xzczd

Comment: I thought too it was another problem.  Of course you can post a question.